make sure docker deamon is running VsCode
I am using docker container in application, using visual studio code in windows.
My server and docker is running fine. I have checked that but I keep getting error make sure docker deamon is running . If I restart machine my docker application run successfully and don't give error. This is irritating and slowing down my work, I have read blogs and answers but nothing worked. Any help would be appreciated!


docker info command is used to display information about Docker on your system. Can you check for yours and if there seems to be any problem?
